# To check if given map is an open map

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Question is to check if the map $f:(0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y)=\ln(x)(\cos y,\sin y)$ is an open map.

I usually try to show my effort, but then here i am totally out..

I have no idea how to start..

Comment: The inverse function theorem deals with most points. Can you identify the problematic points? If you can, it's not very hard to analyse the behaviour at those points.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Determinant of derivative i have found it to be $\frac{1}{x}ln(x)$... It is zero only when $x=1$... I do not know how to tackle this case $x=1$

Comment: So far so good. Next you take a point with $x = 1$, say $(1,0)$ and look what happens there. Fix a small $\varepsilon > 0$ and check how $f$ behaves on $R_{\varepsilon} := (e^{-\varepsilon}, e^{\varepsilon}) \times (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : I think we have $(\eta\cos\eta,\eta\sin\eta) : -\epsilon<\eta<\epsilon$ This is open... So $f$ is open?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ vary independently. For a fixed $y_0 \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, what is $\{ f(x, y_0) : x \in (e^{-\varepsilon},e^{\varepsilon})\}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is the line joining $(-\epsilon \cos y,-\epsilon \sin y)$ to $(\epsilon\cos y,\epsilon \sin y)$.. $f(R_{\epsilon})$ is open square with vertices $(-\epsilon \cos \epsilon,\epsilon\sin \epsilon), (-\epsilon \cos \epsilon,-\epsilon\sin \epsilon),(\epsilon \cos \epsilon,\epsilon\sin -\epsilon),(\epsilon \cos \epsilon,-\epsilon\sin \epsilon)$.. excuse me if this does not make sens..

Comment: That's not correct. Make a sketch of a couple of these lines to see what it looks like in the end.

Comment: Is $f(x,y_0):x\in (e^{-\epsilon},e^{\epsilon})$ correct atleast? @DanielFischer

Comment: Yes, that line is right. But your mental image of what these lines combine to wasn't.

Comment: I am still feeling the same thing.. could not think better.. @DanielFischer

Comment: Draw the lines $t\cdot(\cos \varphi,\sin\varphi),\; t\in (-1,1)$ for say $\varphi = \pm \pi/4$, and then add the lines for a couple of values of $\varphi$ with $\lvert\varphi\rvert < \pi/4$. How does that look?

Comment: @DanielFischer : It seems to be like circle..

Comment: A whole circle, or only a part?

Comment: I am not sure... two one 4 th circles plus something which i am not able to figure out. @DanielFischer

Comment: Two quarter circles, that's good. I don't know what something you see beyond that. So, does that make a neighbourhood of $f(1,0)$?

Comment: I am not able to see may be because there is nothing to see... :D It is a nbd of $f(1,0)$.. @DanielFischer

Comment: It's not. For a neighbourhood, you'd need the full disk. The two circular sectors don't completely wrap $(0,0) = f(1,0)$ when the angle $y$ is constrained to an interval of length less than $\pi$.

Comment: Oh.. Ok... Got it...